# Density of primes of the form $kn\pm r$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

If I'm not mistaken, Dirichlet's theorem states that if $(k,r)=1$ and $r<k$ then $\sharp\{p=kn+r,\mathbb{P}\ni p\leq x\}\sim \sharp\{q=kn-r,\mathbb{P}\ni q\leq x\}\sim\dfrac{1}{\varphi(k)}\pi(x)$.

My first question is: is this true?

If so, can we deduce from this theorem that for almost all positive $r$ (i.e a set of asymptotic density $1$),  $$\lim_{x\to\infty}G_{r}(x):=\sharp\{n\leq x,\vert (n,r)=1, r<n, (n-r,n+r)\in\mathbb{P}^{2}\}=\infty$$ ?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, theorem as you stated it is true. The second statement is true as well, and we can prove it just using infinitude of prime numbers.

Comment: What do you mean by "cardinality of such $n$"?

Comment: Number of $n$ such as in the last expression in Latex.

Comment: But the number of such $n$ might be infinite.

Comment: My formulation is not good. Edit coming.

Comment: Your $G_r(x)$ is, up to a constant, number of prime pairs with difference $2r$. results regarding these are far more complicated than asymptotic Dirichlet. It is conjectured that the limit in your question is infinite for all $r$, but has only been proven for _very_ sparse sets.

Comment: In short: no, asymptotic Dirichlet theorem is not enough to deduce that the limit is infinite for any $r$.

Comment: OK, thank you. Can you please turn your comment into an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to a constant, the function $G_r(x)$ measures the number of prime pairs at distance $2r$ from each other. It is a well-known conjecture stating that this function tends to infinity for every $r$ as $x$ grows without bound. However, the results on bounded intervals containing primes (see [here](http://michaelnielsen.org/polymath1/index.php?title=Bounded_gaps_between_primes#Current_records)) can be used to show that for at least (roughly, up to a multiplicative constant I think) $\log n$ numbers $r$ below $n$ this function grows without bound.

The results regarding bounded prime intervals are much more complicated than asymptotic version of Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions. There is no known way to deduce anything regarding the former using the latter, for a simple reason that it tells us nothing about how primes in *different* arithmetic progressions relate to each other. It would be consistent with Dirichlet theorem that for no number $r$ there are infinitely many prime pairs at distance $2r$ from each other (one can show this by constructing a subset of $\Bbb N$ which satisfies analogue of Dirichlet's theorem, but has gaps growing without bound. I can't give you details of such a construction, but it's easy to convince yourself that such a set exists).